# why $q\left(T\left(x-x_j\right)\right) \rightarrow 0$ implies $T\left(x_j\right) \rightarrow T(x)$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $\mathscr{X}$ and $\mathscr{Y}$ be locally convex vector spaces, let $\mathscr{P}$ and $\mathscr{Q}$ be inducing collections of seminorms for $\mathscr{X}$, respectively $\mathscr{Y}$, and let $T: \mathscr{X} \rightarrow \mathscr{Y}$ be a linear map.
lways continuous).

Now let $\left\{x_j\right\}_{j \in J}$ be a net in $\mathscr{X}$ and $x \in \mathscr{X}$ such that $x_j \rightarrow x$ in $\mathscr{X}$ in this thesis [An Introduction to
FUNCTIONAL SPACES](https://webspace.science.uu.nl/%7Ecrain101/thesis-Marcel-de-Reus.pdf) by Marcel de Reus at page 158 in  Lemma A.1.2 we have

> To prove that $T$ is continuous, we should prove that $T\left(x_j\right) \rightarrow T(x)$ in $\mathscr{Y}$, which is equivalent to the statement that $q\left(T(x)-T\left(x_j\right)\right)=q\left(T\left(x-x_j\right)\right) \rightarrow 0$ in $\mathbb{R}$ for every $q \in \mathscr{Q}$, which in

Why $q\left(T\left(x-x_j\right)\right) \rightarrow 0$ implies  $T\left(x_j\right) \rightarrow T(x)$ ?

This is what I tried.

$q\left(T(x)-T\left(x_j\right)\right)\rightarrow 0$ means that given $\epsilon >0$ there exist an $j_{\epsilon}$ such that $q\left(T(x)-T\left(x_j\right)\right)<\epsilon$ whenever $j>j_{\epsilon}$.

Now  a neighborhood of $U$ of $T(x)$ is of the form
$$U=\{ y:q_1(y-T(x))<\epsilon \wedge... q_k(y-T(x))<\epsilon \}$$

From the expression above we have that $T\left(x_j\right) \in U$ for $j>j_\epsilon$ wich is the definition of convergence to $T(x)$

I am not sure of proof because I am not sure if all my definition are correct.

Comment: Do you know how the topology induced by  a family of semi-norms is defined?

Comment: By semiballs $B_{y, \varepsilon}(p)=\{x \in X: p(x-y)<\varepsilon\}$

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck in the proof?

Comment: $j_\varepsilon=j_{\varepsilon,q}$ in your argument depends also on $q$. If your neighbourhood is given by finitely many $q_1,\ldots,q_k$ you need the directedness of the index set $J$ to find a single $j_\varepsilon$ which is larger than each $j_{\varepsilon,q_k}$.

Comment: Your proof is correct.